# How to specify collation with PDO without SET NAMES?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

We can explicitly set the char set to utf8 when initializing PDO, just add "`charset=utf8`" to the dsn string. But how does one explicitly specify the collation used in MySQL connection when using PDO?

I don't want to use an additional query to do this:

```
SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Is there any way without having to resort to "SET NAMES"? Or, would there be any problem if I don't specify a collation?

Comment: @kavoir.com I think I have a shorter answer to your question. It is a year late, but hey, I just swapped over from MySQLi prepared statements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a two in one answer.

You can set this in the DSN or as MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND (connection options).

DSN is better, i think.

```
$connect = new PDO(
  "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", 
  $user, 
  $pass, 
  array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
  )
);
```

If you specify `UTF-8` you are working with the default collation of `utf8_general_ci`, unless your db table or field uses something different.

If you want the whole server to respond with this default collation then use configuration directives:

```
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci 
character_set_server=utf8
```

So you don't have to specify it on connection everytime.

The collations affect the sorting of chars and is set on the table and fields in your database.
These settings are respected, when querying the table. Make sure they are set.
Use UTF-8 names with the collation set in your db.

---

Your comment:

> "People should know char set and collation are 2 different things."

Let's Quote from the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html) to proof this:

> A `SET NAMES 'charset_name'` statement is equivalent to these three
>   statements:
>
> ```
> SET character_set_client = charset_name;
> SET character_set_results = charset_name;
> SET character_set_connection = charset_name;
> ```
>
> **Setting `character_set_connection` to charset_name also implicitly sets `collation_connection` to the default collation for
>   charset_name.**

My answer: **It works implicitly, unless your tables changes this explicitly.**

---

Question from comment:

> How to make sure I don't mess things up as my tables are not the
>   default collation utf8_general_ci?

**Example: Column collation overrides table collation**

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
    col1 CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin;
```

If both CHARACTER SET X and COLLATE Y are specified on a column, character set X and collation Y are used. The column has character set `utf8` and collation `utf8_unicode_ci` as specified in the table column, while the table is in latin1 + latin1_bin.

**Example: in general table collation is used**

If collation is not explicitly specified on a column/Field, then the table collation is used:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
    col1 CHAR(10)
) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin;
```

col1 has collation latin1_bin.

**If you want `utf8_unicode_ci` collation, set it to your tables in general or to the columns/fields.**

Comment: People should know char set and collation are 2 different things.

Comment: My tables are all in utf8_unicode_ci. I don't have access to configuration directives. Will they be automatically respected?

Comment: i've updated my answer to show that these settings are implicitly respected. **SET NAMES UTF-8 should be enough to implicitly set the collation utf8_unicode_ci**. Hope this works out and maybe this explains, why nobody asks for collation, when working with set names. by the way, it's still possible to do a query with another collation, which would affect the sorting then..

Comment: ok, updated my answer with two examples. it depends, on what you specify on your tables / columns.

Comment: @JensA.Koch Why is this accepted as the answer, when clearly only explicitly stating the collation in syntax can satisfy the question?

Comment: I think the answer was accepted, because i answered the initial question and all additional questions from the comments, which helped the questioner a bit. / One part of the question is `Is there any way without having to resort to "SET NAMES"? Or, would there be any problem if I don't specify a collation?` and i provided a detailed answer with examples, when to leave the things away. So, one part of the answer is: You don't have to (explicitly) specify the COLLATION when using SET NAMES, if your DB is configured correctly.

Answer (score 8):

Question: "How to specify collation with PDO without SET NAMES? .. how does one explicitly specify the collation used in MySQL connection when using PDO?"

Answer: You just cannot do it without using SET NAMES or something similar. Using `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` in the `$options` array of the PDO constuctor is *the only way to **explicitly** set the connection collation* **directly** in your connection code using PDO. Otherwise, you will be relying on something less than explicit syntax (which is not the answer to the question). Certainly, any other method is less direct.

Some versions of MySQL (5.1) have two, 3-byte unicode, uft8 collations (unicode and general). Simply using utf8 in the $dsn string will not *explicitly* choose the "unicode" version or the "general" version of the utf8 collations. PDO is not a mind reader.

Therefore, your options string may look something like this:

```
$options  = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'"];
```

or

```
$options  = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'"];
```

Later versions of MySQL have a 4-byte utf8 unicode implementation. Here, you would specify utf8mb4, not uft8.

```
$options  = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this  ---Done----
[image]

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vocabulary;charset=utf-8', "root", "", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

and in HTML page use

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```