# PHP: remove special characters like � while importing data from CSV to database

Tags: php, csv, str-replace

I created a PHP script that allows me to upload a huge file of data from csv file. While importing, I'd like to replace the special character like **�** to a letter **c**. Below is my code:

```
        $sql ="INSERT INTO bill_of_materials(allotment_code, category_name, activity, quantity, end_unit_quantity, unit, description,
        unit_cost, regular_labor_cost, end_unit_labor_cost, type, batch) VALUES";

        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

          $sql .= "('".implode("', '", explode(";", sanitize($line)))."'),";
          $counter++;
        }

            $sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql) - 1);
             if (mysqli_query($new_conn, $sql) === TRUE) {

                echo 1;

                //database file name
                $new_database_file = $new_database.'.sql';

                if(file_exists('backup/'.$new_database_file)) {

                    unlink('backup/'.$new_database_file);

                    // backup main database

                    $command = "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --host=$host --user=$user --password=$pass $database_name > backup/$new_database_file";
                    system($command);

                } else {
                    // backup main database

                    $command = "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --host=$host --user=$user --password=$pass $database_name > backup/$new_database_file";
                    system($command);
                }
            } else {
                echo $sql;
            }
```

In addition, I have a data from my CSV that is **W2-A1 2/F Front Fa�ade - B** and I'd like to see an output like **W2-A1 2/F Front Facade - B**. How can i do this?

Comment: I guess you are looking for `str_replace()`? [Link to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Hope this helps!

Comment: You should look for `REGEX`

Comment: Looks an encoding issue, Make sure your connection to mysql is set to UTF-8

Comment: maybe try to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: @N. Ivanov i tried str_replace() with no luck :(

Comment: @exussum i guess that's what I'm looking for. I'll try that

Comment: You don't want to replace those "special characters", you want to try to **handle encodings correctly.** Those "special characters" appear when you're *not* handling encodings correctly. The solution is *not* to simply get rid of them.

Comment: @exussum i tried to set it to UTF-8 but i still get the same result.

Comment: @deceze how can I do that sir? I'd like to try that.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure you are using correct [database client charset collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807202/how-to-specify-collation-with-pdo-without-set-names).
If database charset/collation is correct, you may use `preg_replace` to sanitize dirty characters like so:

```
function sanitize($line){
   $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $line); // attempt to translate similar characters
   $clean = preg_replace('/[^\w]/', '', $clean); // drop anything but ASCII
   return $clean;
}
```

If that won't help (e.g. you have truly corrupted binary stream - for example saving into CSV from old Excel source file) you may want to use binary translated characters (first you must find out corrupted binary sequence e.g. by dumping it via `chr(ord($line[$position]))`) - example:

```
function sanitize($line){
    $map = [
        // corrupted chars sequence -> fixed chars
        "\xC3\xA8" => 'č',
        "\xC3\x88" => 'Č',
        "\xC3\xB9" => 'ů',
        "\xC3\x99" => 'Ů',
        "\xC3\xAC" => 'ě',
        "\xC3\x8C" => 'Ě',
        "\xC3\xB8" => 'ř',
        "\xC3\x98" => 'Ř',
        "\x53\xC2\x8D" => 'Š',
        "\xC2\xA9" => 'Š',
    ];
    return str_replace(array_keys($map), $map, $line);
}
```

Comment: this works for me. thanks.

Comment: This isn't a good solution. Fix the core issue instead of patching over it. If you set the entire pipeline of code to the correct charset, that will fix your issue - properly. The word "corrupted" is not correct in this context either, it's just a different encoding.

Comment: @Qirel Please note that the very first sentence recommends to fix database client collation/charset. Suggested PHP functions are a fallback solution user cannot fix that.

Comment: Fixing the charset issue will prevent further encoding issues, this approach will still have broken encoding for any new data. It might be a workaround for data that's already of the wrong charset - but shouldn't substitute a proper fix for new data entries.

Comment: @Qirel This question does not say anything whether source CSV files are or are not corrupted. It's your own assumption. It might be truly corrupted if e.g. saved from old Excel 2003 file with windows-1250 encoding into UTF-8. I had this case recently - my task was to import hundreds of old CSV files from third parties, while many files had corrupted encoding and no way to obtain fixed old files. Binary characters translation was the only way to fix it. Therefore setting proper database client connection charset may or may not fix the issue.