# SQL Server values with weird characters returns NULL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I need to write a synchronisation between records in SQL Server and our CMS. Everything works fine, but a few records have weird characters.

When I look them up in SQL Management Studio I can see the value "Anselm Gr**ü**n". When I execute the query in PHP PDO the value is "NULL"

PHP code to execute the query:

```
    function getResultFromSqlServer($queryString){
    $db = new PDO('odbc:Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server; Server=****,1433; Database=Winbooks; UID=****; PWD=****');
    $query = $db->query($queryString);
    $result = array();
    while ($row = $query->fetch()){
        $result[] = $row;
    }//while
    return $result;
}//getResultFromSqlServer
```

Query:

```
SELECT name1 as 'Naam', insleep as 'Slapend',
       c_webshop as 'Webshop', tr_groep as 'Groep',
       tr_subgroe as 'Subgroep' 
FROM art 
WHERE (tr_subgroe LIKE '".$logisticsCode."%' 
       OR tr_groep LIKE '".$logisticsCode."%') 
      AND insleep = 0 
ORDER BY name1
```

(I know I should use prepared statements, but this is only for testing purposes)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Add "charset=utf8;" to your PDO() string? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807202/how-to-specify-collation-with-pdo-without-set-names

Comment: I think you're on a wild goose chase here. A return value of `NULL` usually means that no row matched your conditions. Weird characters can get garbled but usually don't have the effect that a fetch will return `NULL`. Then again, you're using ODBC, so who knows?

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't so clear. I get all the records, but the value that has an "ü" returns a NULL-value, but I get the whole record.

Comment: Reduce your query to a simple test case (e.g. `SELECT "Anselm Grün"` or `SELECT name1 FROM art WHERE name1 LIKE "Anselm%"`) and include sample output (e.g. `print_r($row)`.)

Comment: Also, you need to be starting with prepared statements with parameters or you're wide open to SQL injection attacks. What difference does one line of code "only for testing" make?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use unicode search

```
SELECT name1 as 'Naam', insleep as 'Slapend',
       c_webshop as 'Webshop', tr_groep as 'Groep',
       tr_subgroe as 'Subgroep' 
FROM art 
WHERE (tr_subgroe LIKE N'".$logisticsCode."%' 
       OR tr_groep LIKE N'".$logisticsCode."%') 
      AND insleep = 0 
ORDER BY name1
```

Comment: Doesn't work either. I still get the record, but the column that contains ü is empty